# Is each compact metric space a subset of a compact absolute 1-Lipschitz retract?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

A metric space $X$ is called an *absolute $L$-Lipschitz retract* if for any metric space $Y$ containing $X$ there exists a Lipschitz retraction $r:Y\to X$ with Lipschitz constant $Lip(r)\le L$.

**Question.** Is each compact metric space isometric to a subset of a compact absolute 1-Lipschitz retract?

**Remark 1.** Using almost isometric embeddings into the Banach space $c_0$, it can be shown that each compact metric space $X$ is a subset of a compact absolute $(1+\varepsilon)$-Lipschitz retract $Y$, where $\varepsilon$ is any positive real number. The space $Y$ is a suitable cube $\prod_{n\in\omega}[-a_n,a_n]$ in $c_0$ with a bit distorted metric.

**Remark 2.** There exists also a functorial construction of an embedding of compact metric space $X$ into a compact absolute 8-Lipschitz retract $A(X)$. Given a compact metric space $X$, consider the isometric embedding $X\subset\ell_\infty$ identifying each point $x\in X$ with the distance function $d_X(x,\cdot)$. Next, take the closed convex hull $conv(X)$ of $X$ in $\ell_\infty$. Finally, consider the hyperspace $A(X)$ of non-empty convex compact subsets of $conv(X)$, endowed with the Hausdorff metric. By Theorem 1.7 in the book "Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis" by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss, the compact metric space $A(X)$ is an absolute 8-Lipschitz retract. I do not know if the constant 8 can be replaced by a smallest constant (say 1).

---

**Added at Edit.** Thanks to the comment of @Wlod AA, I have found an answer to my question on [page 32](https://books.google.com/books?id=lXZ95EKwjYUC&pg=PA32) of the book of Benyamini and Lindenstrauss. They write that [Isbell in 1964](https://eudml.org/doc/139281) suggested the construction of the injective envelope of a metric space, which is the smallest 1-Lipschitz AR containing a given metric space. For a compact metric space its injective envelope is compact, too.

Comment: "is a subset" purports to mean "is isometric to a subset"?

Comment: @YCor Correct! And corrected.

Comment: A compact metric space $X$ can be isometrically embedded into $\ell_\infty(X)$, and its closed convex envelope there is a compact subset $K$. Isn't any convex compact subset $K$ of $\ell_\infty(X)$ an absolute $1$-Lipschitz retract?

Comment: I think it is, e.g. according to the characterization given in Prop 1.4 in Benyiamini-Lindenstrauss' GNFA ("A metric space $K$ is $1$-Lipschitz AR  iff it is metrically convex and has the binary intersection property")

Comment: @PietroMajer I do not think that each convex compact subset of $\ell_\infty$ is a 1-Lipschitz AR. It this case a compact convex set in any Banach space would be a 1-Lipschitz AR, which is not true, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291740/which-banach-spaces-are-absolute-lipschitz-extensors-for-compacta

Comment: @PietroMajer To force a subset of $\ell_\infty$ to have the binary intersection property, you should make it order-convex. But the order-convex closure of a subset in $\ell_\infty$ needs not be compact (in contrast to $c_0$, where compact sets have compact order-convex hulls).

Comment: Thank you Taras, I see. Doesn't this quite answer negatively to the question? (For if X admits such a 1-Lip AR compact superset K, we have wlog $X\subset K\subset \ell_\infty$, and $K$ must contain the order closure of $X$, which is not always the case as you are saying ).  (In fact I'm not sure if this argument is correct since the above embedding of X depends on K)

Comment: @PietroMajer The order convexity is a sufficient but not necessary condition of being 1-Lipschitz AR. In fact, there are many non-equivalent embeddings into $\ell_\infty$. For example, the unit interval $[0,1]$ is isometric to an order-convex set in $\ell_\infty$ but can also be re-embedded as a diagonal of $\ell^\infty$ and then it is not order-convex, moreover, its order-convex hull is not compact.

Comment: @PietroMajer Ideally, it would be nice to have a canonical construction making from a compact metric space $X$ a 1-Lipschitz AR. There is such a construction producing a 8-Lipschitz AR. I will write it as a Remark in my question.

Comment: Have you tried the naïve idea of taking the Banach-space ultraproduct of those embeddings into $c_0$ with $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Comment: It is not clear why the ultraproduct of those (increasing) cubes will be compact. It may happen that as a result you will just obtain the unit ball in $\ell_\infty$, which is a universal 1-Lipschitz AR but is not compact.

Comment: @TarasBanakh, yes, but how about the w*-topology of the unit ball of $\ell_\infty$? The idea would be that in finite dimensions the norm metric metrises the w*-topology. More precisely my question would be: isn't the unit ball of $\ell_\infty$ with the w*-topology suitably metrised (or some quotient thereof) the sought space? We can actually make these sets increasing by your agument.

Comment: Taras and/or authors Benyamini and Lindenstrauss have written carefully that *Isbell in 1964 suggested the construction of the injective envelope of a metric space, which is the smallest 1-Lipschitz AR containing a given metric space*. You may have an easier time to read "*Linearization...*" from Bull.Acad.Polon.Sci.**16** (1968), pp. 189-193. This paper defines/constructs the metric envelope (and proves its properties), and it proves that the metric envelope of a Banach space is the metric Banach envelope.

Comment: @Pietro Mayer, let $\ X\ $ be (Hausdorff) compact. Then $\ C(X)\ $ is injective $\ \Leftrightarrow\ X\ $ is extremely disconnected, i.e. the closure of any open set is open. There are no such metric compact metric spaces except for finite spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classical paper on the given theme is by [Aronszajn and Panitchkpakdi](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103043960). I am pretty sure that it contains the required result about embedding metric spaces into *metric* absolute retracts, i.e. in Lip$_1$ category, and perhaps about embeddings compact metric spaces in compact metric absolute retracts. Indeed, these authors have introduced the notion of the hyper-convex metric spaces which is equivalent to metrically injective spaces (i.e. in Lip$_1$ category, which I call simply *metric category* or *Met* for short).

This and further results are contained in later papers by John Isbell and (a bit later and independently) by wh.

---

Let me provide perhaps the simplest embedding of arbitrary compact metric space $\ \mathbf X:=(X\ d)\ $ into a compact metric absolute retract.

Let $\ Y:=\mbox{Met}_\delta\ (\mathbf X)\ $ be the set of all metric maps
$\ f:X\rightarrow[0;\delta],\ $ where $\ \delta\ $ is the diameter of $\ \mathbf X\ $ (*metric maps* means Lip$_1).\ $ Then $\ Y\ $ in its uniform distance function is compact, it's hyper-convex i.e. it's an injective metric space (metric absolute retract), and the embedding $\ i:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is given by Kuratowski-Wojdysławski formula:

$$ \forall_{s\ t\in X}\ \ (i(s))(t)\ :=\ d(s\ t) $$

> *(You need to be archeological to hear about this stuff).*

**Theorem** Let $\ \mathbf X:=(X\ d)\ $ be an arbitrary non-empty metric space of an arbitrary finite diameter. Let
               $\ -\infty\le a\le b\le\infty.\ $

Then space
         $\ Y\ \:=\ \mbox{Met}(\mathbf X\,\ \mathbb R\!\cap\![a;b])\ $
of all metric functions $\ f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R\cap[a;b]\ $
is hyper-convex.

**Proof**   Let $\ \emptyset\ne F\subseteq Y $
and *radia* $\ r:F\rightarrow[0;\infty)\ $ be such that

$$ \forall_{f\ g\in F}\ r_f+r_g\ge |f-g| $$

Define $\ c : X\rightarrow \mathbb R\!\cap\![a;b]\ $ as follows:

$$ \forall_{x\in X}\ \ c(x)\ :=\ \max(a\ \ sup_{_{x\in X}}\ (f(x)-r_f)) $$

Then, by routine applications of the triangle inequality, the function $\ c\ $ has what it takes:

$$ c\ \in Y\cap\bigcap_{f\in F} B(f\ r_f) $$

where $\ B(f\ r_f)\ $ is the ball centered in $\ f,\ $ of radius $\ r_f.$

Comment: I've been thinking about this paper as this is the main tool in Lindenstrauss' proof of the fact if a Banach space is $(1+\varepsilon)$-injective for all $\varepsilon > 0$, then it is injective (see also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132610/1-epsilon-injective-banach-spaces-complex-scalars). Is there a chance for such result in the metric case?

Comment: @Wlod AA Thank you very much for your answer. But why is your space $Y$ hyperconvex? Is there any reference for this important fact? Cause I cannot find mentioning the space $Met_\delta(X)$ in the paper of Aronszajn and Panickpakdi :(

Comment: @TomekKania, thank you for the link.

Comment: Taras, I have borrowed the consistent metric terminology (metric maps, MET or Met, etc) from my old papers (wh). I will provide a proof of $\ Y\ $ being hyper-convex in my *answer*--you'll see that it's very straightforward.